# Calculate UILabel height for text with different languages and emojis in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, emoji

I need to calculate the frame size for given text that may be in english/emoji/other languages.

The way I did it was:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[style setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style};
CGSize rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(containerWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                            attributes:attributes
                               context:nil].size;
```

It works fine as long as I do not use emoji. It seems that the emoji line height/font size is different than regular fonts.

I saw that people tried solving it in different ways such as:
http://youbbe.xyz/issue/4987325/ios-emoji-messed-up-in-uilabel

This solution works for emojis but not for English/other fonts.

See example image:

[image]

As you can see, just text is calculated fine (first box) but text+emoji is not calculated correctly (second box).

I'm really surprised that there is no easy solution for this problem.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: try With Below Function  but you have to use Send Attributed Text And Width of TextVew and  function returns a height of textview
`- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString *)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [textView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    //textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    return size.height+10;
}`

Comment: check out this .. [article](http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/)

Comment: What is `containerWidth`? Where are you setting it? What does the code look like that actually sets the label's frame?

Comment: Did you try with a UITextView and sizeToFit() ?

Comment: Try with a textView, I have no problem at all using it and I don't think it will make a big difference for you...

Comment: using UITextView will effect performance -- it is much slower, so don't use it in UITableView

Comment: to create a property for UITextView Height Constraint.it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

With a UILabel you can simply say:

```
CGSize size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(containerWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

Have you tried this? I don't think emoji have a different line height, but rather they typically take up the entire line height.

You can just say `[label sizeToFit];` and then get the size from the frame, (e.g. `CGSize size = label.frame.size;`). This seems the most consistently accurate way of getting the right size for different font sizes.

There is some code [here](https://gist.github.com/bgayman/da9ae1f752e9062fa099) that you can copy and paste into a playground and see the different results.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work... I see many people answer the same way but nothing that really works...

Comment: You should show what you are getting and what you're expecting.

Comment: if you don't understand what is the problem - do not bother replying. As I told you more than once and you can read the thread and see the example - sizeToFit does not work.

Comment: You should include what you've already tried in your question to save time and frustration. Also, simply saying "it doesn't work" is not helpful nor constructive. I've provided code that works under certain conditions. You should be more specific about the conditions for which it's not working. For example what version iOS are targeting? What does the rest of your view hierarchy look like? What string are you using? What values are getting from the code that's not working? Are you using auto layout? All of these things could be relevant to your problem.

Comment: as I said before - I tried all the examples provided here. I supplied images with example of exactly the problem. When using an emoji - the height is not calculated correctly. I'm not using auto layout. I only have a UILable. I'm not targeting any specific ios version.

Comment: What values do you get for height? Does it change when you mix different types of characters? If it's just a label, why does it appear in a rounded rect? Why does it not clip at the bounds of the rounded rect but several pixels from the bottom? Provide the code where you are setting the frame of the label. Add these answers to the original question. Don't ask a question then add comments to answers like "I tried that already." State what you've already tried upfront and edit your question to reflect solutions that didn't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is set text with attribute string and specify paragraph style

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5;
paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 1.1;
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 16;
```

`maximumLineHeight` can limit height of line which has emoji in it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to an `NSAttributedString` then use this category:

```
- (CGFloat)heightForAttributedStringWithEmojisForWidth:(CGFloat)width {
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)self);
    CFRange fitRange;
    CGSize frameSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, [self length]), NULL, CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), &fitRange);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    return ceilf(frameSize.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//may be it will help for you
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    //set the line break mode
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = yourLabel.lineBreakMode;

    NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:yourLabel.font,
                              NSFontAttributeName,
                              paragraphStyle,
                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                              nil];


    CGRect rect = [yourLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(yourLabel.frame.size.width, yourLabel)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:attrDict
                                                  context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
```

Comment: as mentioned to other people answered here. This solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)text {

    CGFloat offset = 5.f;

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:textHeight];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            font, NSFontAttributeName,
                            paragraph, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];

    //size of one field
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

    CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(320.f - offset * 2.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                     options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                  attributes:attributes
                                     context:nil];

    return CGRectGetHeight(textRect);

}
```